# Regex - matching leading and trailing spaces, spaces between opening and closing brackets and words, but not between words

Tags: ruby, regex

I apologize if this question has already been answered, but I have searched and cannot find the answer.  I am trying to write a regex that will match all leading and trailing space, the spaces between the opening and closing bracket and the word, but will not match the spaces between words. The following are string format examples of the data I'm parsing:

```
[Header]  
   [  SomeSpace]     
      [  Some1 More Space 15  ]
```

- no leading and trailing space, no space between brackets and only one word.
- some leading and trailing space, space between the opening bracket and trailing space.
- some leading space, space between word and digits, space between the opening and closing bracket, and trailing space.

The closest single regex I've come up with is:

```
/[^\[\]a-zA-Z\d]/
```

But I cannot seem to unmatch only the spaces between the words and digits...

The ruby code I currently am using as a workaround is:

```
line.gsub!(/^\s*/, "")
line.gsub!(/\[/, "")
line.gsub!(/\]/, "")
s = line.gsub!(/^\s*|\s*$/, "")
s = "[" + s + "]\n"
```

Obviously, not very pretty...

Any help to streamline this into an elegant gsub line is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to turn this text

```
[Header]  
   [  SomeSpace]     
      [  Some1 More Space 15  ]
```

into this:

```
[Header]
[SomeSpace]
[Some1 More Space 15]
```

This regex will do the job. The key addition here is the non-greedy `?` quantifier on the inner character class. This makes the character class match as little as possible and leaves the trailing space within the brackets (if there is any) for the following greedy `\s*`.

```
s/^\s*\[\s*([\w\s]*?)\s*\]\s*$/[$1]/g
```

Ruby:

```
line.gsub! /^\s*\[\s*([\w\s]*?)\s*\]\s*$/, '[\\1]'
```

`sed` (ugly and most likely non-performant.. I'm no `sed` master!)

```
sed -Ee "s/^ *\[([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\] *$/\\1/g" -e "s/^ */[/g" -e "s/ *$/]/g" infile
```

Comment: `sed` does not support non-greedy quantifiers — I'll see if I can think up an alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match all extra spaces for replacement:

```
/(?<=^|\[)\s+|\s+(?=$|\])|(?<=\s)\s+/
```

- The first part will match all leading spaces at the start and inside bracket.
- The second part will match all trailing spaces at the end and inside bracket.
- The last part will detect sequence of 2 or more spaces and remove the extra ones.

Just replace the matches with empty string.

**Test data**

```
    [Header]  
   [  SomeSpace]     
      [  Some1 More Space 15  ]       
   [    Super    Space     ]     
  [    ]
  [ ]
   []
[a]
[a ]
[ a]
[   a   ]
[a a]
[a   a   a      a a  b]   [   dasdasd   dsd   ]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input,  I think it will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about elegant but simplest is probably:

```
line.gsub /^\s*(\[)\s*|\s*(\])\s*$/, '\\1\\2'
```